# Choose multiple options from select box using ng-options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume my html looks like:

```
<div>
<select  class="topcoat-select"  ng-model="myselect" ng-options="o.cost as (o.attr_value+'-$'+' '+o.cost) group by o.attribute_text for o in options" ng-change="itemchange()" >  
    <option  value="">--Select Options--</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Now I am able to select only single option and I get the value of that single option in the ng-model. But I want to select multiple options and I want to get the value of selected options in ng-model.

Is it possible to select multiple options from a single select box in angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `multiple="multiple"` to your `select` element declaration. Then, the selected options in your `ng-model` will be a comma-separated array of values.

```
<select ng-options="record.id as record.value for record in records" ng-model="output" multiple="multiple"></select>

<button ng-click="alertValues()">Click Me!</button>

$scope.output = "";

$scope.records = [{
    id: 1,
    value: "One",
}, {
    id: 2,
    value: "Two",
}, {
    id: 3,
    value: "Three",
}];   

$scope.alertValues = function(){        
    alert($scope.output);        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/6W8Xg/1/